# adding a new column IsActive and set its data type to bit and want to set it to not null. Cannot Insert null in to column IsActive

Tags: sql-server

adding a new column IsActive and set its data type to bit and want to set it to not null. but getting an error. Cannot Insert null in to column IsActive.

[I have not found any solution of this in google.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQYCQ.png)

Comment: Wait...if you made the `isActive` column a _non_ nullable `BIT` column, then why would you expect to be able to insert a `NULL` value into it?

Comment: basically it is allowing null value. and i want to set to not null. when i am setting it to not null it is giving me the error.

Comment: bit has  0 or 1 , if  you want to set  any default values use default constraint  i.e.. 0,1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a default value when adding a new bit NOT NULL column:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD IsActive bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

Comment: If you don't *want* the default going forwards, remember to *name* the constraint so that you can drop it straight afterwards.

Comment: (And many people would argue that you should name all of your constraints anyway)